# Accessing nodejs public files in subfolder with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I need access file in a node server with nginx proxy.

I have a node server running on 3100 port.

```
....
app.use("/public", express.static(uploadConfig.directory));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "100MB" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "6MB" }));
....
```

The public files I want to be served are in public and public/downloads folders

I need access using the browser:
https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx

But I get an error in chrome console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/css/vendor.bd22678e.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/css/app.259dd189.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx:1 
                
GET https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/js/vendor.fb91b0e7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/js/vendor.fb91b0e7.js' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx:1 
        
GET https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/js/app.ee91e959.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
f5c65633-102f-41b0-b1ff-d6674262dc79_contatos_exportados.xlsx:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://growx.growm.com.br/public/downloads/js/app.ee91e959.js' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Is this a nginx configuration problem in my code?
How could I fix it?

My node folders are:

```
..
\src
\public
   \downloads
package.json
....
```

// NGINX

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                   1h;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  1h; # set this to your needs
    text/css                    1h;
    application/javascript      1h;
    ~image/                     1h;
}

server {
        server_name growx.growm.com.br www.growx.growm.com.br;
        root     /web/growticket-frontend/dist/pwa;


        #cors
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

        #gzip compression
        gzip            on;
        gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
        gzip_min_length 1000;

        charset utf-8;        
        
        #main app index.html
        location  / {
         #access_log off;
         expires $expires;
         index    index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        
        location ~ ^/(api)/ {
            #add new
            expires $expires;
            access_log off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3100$request_uri;
        }
        
        location ~ ^/(public|common)/ {
                expires $expires;
            access_log off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3100$request_uri;
        }
        #socket io
        location ~* \.io {
            access_log off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3100;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/growx.growm.com.br/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/growx.growm.com.br/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = growx.growm.com.br) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name growx.growm.com.br;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```